# How do I view Linux file system drives on a Windows machine?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

I have an external hard drive that was used on a linux system to store a bunch of data.  I no longer have access to that linux system any more but would like to view the files on a Windows machine.  Is there a way to view these files without the use of a virtual machine, or booting into a linux distro?

Comment: What filesystem is used on the external HDD?

Answer (score 0):

Linux File Systems Are Different from Windows And You Cant Reach them in Windows Explorer You Can Use These Softwares:

[Freeware Linux Reader for Windows Get access to any files from Windows!](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

[Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs)